Quiero que mi aplicacion detecte de donde viene la Request
como estan?
Estoy buscando la forma de hacer que mi servidor ( en asp.net core 6 ) detecte que de donde esta llegando la request, osea que busco que solo se pueda hacer desde mi link de pagina web ( mi front ), solo permitiendo algunas ips, pero permitiendo en general si la peticion viene desde el front sin importar la ip desde la que se ejecute. en un inicio intente tomando el campo referer de la request, pero este se puede modificar incluso desde postman osea que no me sirve.
alguien tiene idea de que puedo hacer?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Quiero que eservidor solo asepte meticiones http desde el front, osea la direccion de dominio, pero al momento de hacer la peticion desde postman me lo permite sin importar las cors

porque el cors, es solo un tema de navegadores. Cualquiera haciendo una llamada desde cualquier lado, que no sea desde un navegador, podra hacerlo sin problema, suplantando todo lo que quieras. Para eso, necesitas segurizar la llamada, con algun metodo de seguridad...

Así como lo planteas, no es posible
